# 60's-70's film about a boy working in a printing press shop, set in Europe during the Renaissance

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie on TV sometime around 1982 or something like that; it looked like it was filmed in the 60's or 70's. I remember it was set in Renaissance-era Europe and there was a boy who worked as an apprentice in a printing press shop...

He had this mysterious friend from another world/star, some other boy who could turn himself invisible and had a telekinetic power.  No one else knew about this "secret" friend.  At the end of the movie, the "secret" friend turned into a small ball of blue light and disappeared into the sky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Mysterious Stranger from Mark Twain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Stranger#Film_versions, the version with Lance and Chris.

Comment: Could you edit this to explain how it matches or at least provide a basic synopsis?

Comment: Despite the minimality, this is definitely the right answer though.

Comment: yes! that's it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the 1982 tv movie *The Mysterious Stranger* mentioned in relesabe's answer, and thought of it as a possible answer as soon as I read the question.

Mark Twain wrote several different more or less complete versions of *The Mysterious stranger* and the book published after his death combined plot elements from at least two versions.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Stranger[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Stranger%5B1%5D)

As I dimly remember, the tv movie was set in late medieval or early renaissance Austria, and I think set in a castle which was, rather unusually, occupied by a printing establishment.  The printers had a big order from a university to print a large number of bibles, and success or failure to fill the order would be a big deal for them.  The protagonist was a teenage printers apprentice and the "mysterious stranger" in the title was another teenage boy.  I might not have seen the whole movie because I don't remember much about the plot.

I remember Fred Gwynne as one of the adult characters, and he is listed among the actors in *The Mysterious stranger*.

[https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084374/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast[2]](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084374/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast%5B2%5D)

The young actors were Chris Makepeace (b. 1964) as August Feldner and Lance Kerwin (b. 1960) as Number 44, the "Mysterious Stranger".

Comment: yes!!!! that's it thank you so much :)