# French movie: a few people gather in a cold/frozen place; guy hides in locomotive and gets shot

Tags: story-identification, movie

It might be ~20 years ago that I saw part of this movie on TV in French language (maybe on *TV5*, maybe on *Arte*), but I'm not entirely sure it was of French origin. All scenes were calm and without action sequences - it all seemed to be quite dystopian, as if more and more things just stop working. The atmosphere was full of hopelessness and abandonment, and all scenes displayed coldness, mostly through ice - as if it's a slow freezing apocalypse.

- One scene had a guy who was hiding in a locomotive that looked like [an ordinary diesel shunting engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Indian_Diesel_Loco.JPG) in black, but he just used a door to a cabin where the engines are supposed to be. At least one other guy hunted and found him, then they had a brief conversation - the former guy repeatedly said the phrase "le président" amongst other words. Then he was shot by his hunter. Steam was seen (as per the engine, I guess), and both wore long dark coats, protecting them against winter-like weather.
- Another scene had a dozen adults of middle-to-advanced age in a big hall, dressed in fine suits for a party that was no longer going on, and little light. There was a band of 4-7 people that acted like humanoids - they were still playing but nobody wanted it, so one guy was trying to stop them by repeatedly crossing and moving his arms through a light beam from above (in this rather dark hall), as if the band would be switched on/off through that photo sensor. It didn't work.
- Another scene was with the same people and one of them wanted a massage - one female humanoid then came to perform that task, and she looked a bit maniacal (staring). After massagin the person for a while, she broke their arm or leg for no reason - the person screamed. Maybe there was a large pool nearby.

The movie was fully colored and might have been produced during the era of 1980 to 2000. Based on the humanoids (just normal persons/actors), I suppose it's displaying the future. I have no clue who acted in it or what its title could be - but I was always interested in seeing it in full.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the movie you're looking for, please upvote that answer and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark beneath the voting buttons.

Comment: @LogicDictates thanks for the hint. If you look at my badges and at my network profile you can verify I'm used to how things work here. I don't automatically upvote answers that I accept, but upvote all answers showing effort or rare knowledge.

Comment: Understood. That previous comment is just something I automatically post when I see someone labelled as a new contributor, as new users often fail to accept or upvote answers unless they're reminded to do so. There was a user who'd been registered here for two years who confessed that he wasn't aware of the practice of accepting answers.

Comment: @LogicDictates you'd also want to note that while acceptance does help for bookkeeping in story-id questions, and is therefore rather fine to nudge into, asking for an upvote sounds like blowing your own horn and pretty much throws modesty out the window.

Comment: @Jenayah - An upvote just indicates that an answer is useful, and if an answer correctly identifies the story someone is looking for, it surely follows that it's useful, no? Also, I requested that an upvote be given to _anyone_ who provided the correct answer, and while I believed I'd provided the correct answer in this case, [I've made the same request in threads where I hadn't posted an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243342/60s-70s-film-about-a-boy-working-in-a-printing-press-shop-set-in-europe-durin#comment667990_243342).

Comment: @LogicDictates no, not necessarily. While users are free to vote how they want, a one-liner "it's [title] by [author]", as the one you provided as an example, is not really an instance of a _useful_ answer. For story-ids we want the Q/A pair to be detailed and stand on its own, not rely on an external link. A useful story-id answer at the very minimal least includes a blurb copy-pasted from somewhere, and a better answer includes quotes, custom recollections, stuff that's in line with the specific details provided in the question.

Comment: @Jenayah - A minimal answer like that isn't ideal for the site in general, but it was clearly helpful as far as the OP was concerned, as evidenced by their response ( _"yes! that's it, thank you so much!"_).

Comment: @LogicDictates but the matter isn't about "as far as OP being concerned". Stack Exchange sites do not revolve around OPs, but around creating a repository of encyclopaedia-like Q/As standing on their own for future readers... Which all correct answers may not be.

Comment: @Jenayah I consider my Q useful for describing 3 scenes and the A useful for then naming the movie title, linking to it, citing the summary and even finding a YT video. Both Q&A give future searchers more chances to find what they want because of all the text and phrases. The only details to add are alternative titles like "_A luxusbunker_", "_Бункер Палас хотел_" and "_Бункер Палас-отель_".

Comment: @AmigoJack indeed the current Q/A pair is quite a nice one. The other answer linked in the comments, less so; other than that I'm talking about the general situation.

Comment: @Jenayah - I agree that detailed answers are better for the site in general, but an OP isn't obliged to take that into account. They're entitled to upvote an answer solely on the basis that it was useful _to them_. And if someone provides them with the info they needed (even if it's just the title) to ID the story they were looking for, then that answer _was_ useful to them, regardless of whether it was useful to anyone else. SE may not revolve around the the OP's point of view, but their individual decision to upvote an answer or not does.

Comment: @LogicDictates in that case, you may want to phrase your boxed comment into `please consider upvoting that answer, as well as marking it as accepted by clicking [...]` rather than this current imperative `please upvote and accept`.

Comment: @Jenayah - Inserting the word "consider" into the comment doesn't substantively alter its meaning or intent. It was always a polite request, rather than a command, hence the use of the word "please". Also, several such comments have been upvoted by other users, which suggests that others understand that those comments were made in a good spirit.

Comment: @LogicDictates agree to disagree, it adds a layer of "you _can_, but it would be okay if you knew you could and deliberately chose not to". As per the comment upvote bit, I don't think that this is a good indicator as only the folks who _did_ agree upvoted - comments can't be downvoted, hence you have no idea how many user disagree on the phrasing.

Comment: Thank you @AmigoJack, I've been wondering about this very same film but never took the time to ask. Also saw it in France when I was young and mainly remembered the dystopian feel, a locomotive and black water coming out of the shower. I don't know if you've played Horizon Zero Dawn but this movie was what popped into my head when I learned of the Elysium bunker.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pretty sure this is *[Bunker Palace Hôtel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunker_Palace_H%C3%B4tel)* (1989).

[image]

> In the imaginary dictatorship of a futuristic world, rebellion has broken out. The men in power scramble to the 'Bunker Palace Hotel', a safehouse built long ago for this contingency. A rebel spy sneaks in and observes the raving of the powerful and decadent inhabitants. They wonder what has happened to their leader, who has not arrived.

It is a French film, and it definitely has scenes with locomotives (the first one is about 8 minutes in), the scene with the party and the humanoid band (about 32 minutes in), and the one with a female humanoid giving a man a massage by a pool, before breaking his leg (about 45 minutes in).

Comment: Exactly! At 23:18 the locomotive scene is just like I remember it. How do you happen to know this movie and also its details? It looks like an almost unknown entry that nobody ever seemed to have noticed. Finally!

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the film, but Wikipedia has a [list of post-apocalyptic movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_apocalyptic_films) organised by the decade of release. I started looking at the ones released from 1980-1989, and the title _Bunker Palace Hôtel_ immediately leaped out at me, as some of the scenes you described (especially the party in the big hall) sounded like they could've be set in a hotel. I then looked it up on YouTube to confirm that it contained the relevant  scenes.

Comment: Thanks alot - I've encountered enough Wikipedia lists myself but never assumed this an option to check for existence, nor would I have associated a hotel. That list will certainly help me again in the future, and I appreciate when workflows are explained.

Comment: Enki Bilal? I didn't know he's a movie director too. He's pretty well known for his comics, and he has a very distinctive style. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nikopol_Trilogy for example.